# How can I use a diff and a patch to compare two pcap files?

Tags: binary, diff, patch, pcap, delta

I want to do a diff between two pcap files so I did:

```
diff -u file1.pcap file2.pcap > file3.diff
```

or

```
diff --binary file1.pcap file2.pcap > file3.diff
```

then I applied a patch :

```
patch -i file3.diff difference.pcap
```

and I got the following error message :

> Only garbage was found in the patch input file

Any help please ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve with this. What kind of strange use case is this where you expect that simply diffing pcap files yield useful results and patching based on the diff somehow makes sense. Also, normal diff has no `--binary` option and normal `patch` cannot handle binary inputs.

Comment: What is `difference.pcap`? With GNU patch and diff, you can do `diff -ua in1 in2 > dif; patch -i dif in1 -o in2.new`

Comment: @ Steffen Ullrich  :  i want simple to get the difference between two pcap files. For me the difference is also a pcap file. I used diff -u (without a) but i got the same error message that why I used --binary

Comment: @Jhnc : thanks for your help. What's the extension of dif file in your command  please ?

Comment: `diff` doesn't produce pcap files, it produces specially-formatted diff files (which can be read by `patch`. You can give them any extension you want - `diff` and `patch` don't care.

Comment: Thank you so much jhnc. it works now but I have just another problem concerning the files size. After doing:  diff -ua file1.pcap file2.pcap > dif.pcap and patch -i dif.pcap -o delta.pcap (to save the difference into delta.pcap). the size are not compliant: file1 (861Mo) file2 (836Mo) and delta.pcap (836Mo). It's not compliant the delta.pcap file must have 25Mo as size. Isn't it ? I remind that my goal is doing the difference between file1.pcap and file2.pcap and save the difference in delta.pcap